# Using jQuery Mobile, onload function not firing in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a `index.html` file with following syntax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="occassion.html">
  <img class="frametoicon" src="img/occasion.png" />
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

then I have `occassion.html` page which has `body onload` function as follows

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<title>Occassion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function loaded() {
        alert("hii");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loaded()">
</body>
</html>
```

but `onload` function is not firing up....if I try to refresh the page (`occassion.html`) then `onload` function gets fired up... why it is not working when navigated from `index.html`?

If I remove the jQuery files, then it works as expected....what I am missing to add?

This is also not working

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        loaded();
    });
```

Edit

I added

```
 <script>
    $(document).bind("pagechange", function (event, data) {
        console.log(data);
        var toPage = data.toPage[0].id;
        alert(toPage);
        if (toPage == "page2")
            alert("hello");
    });
</script>
```

and put the following in occassion.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
 hello
 </div>
```

To my surprise not even the alert(hello) is firing but also hello is also not displayed and alert(topage) is coming empty..

How is it? what's missing

Comment: why are you using `onLoad` instead of `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Not an answer, but the correct spelling is occasion....

Comment: You are using jQuery - don't use `onload`but rely on a `$(function(){ .. })` block inside your script.

Comment: If you're still using inline JavaScript while you have jQuery at your disposal, you really need to re-consider your whole approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery Mobile uses AJAX to pull pages into the DOM, that's how it can transition between pages. When jQuery Mobile does this, there is a good chance it's doing it after the `window.load` event fires, so that event will generally not fire unless you refresh the page (then `window.load` will fire again). It seems possible that a user could click a link and have it load before the `window.load` event fires, but I wouldn't expect that to be the norm.

The fix is to use jQuery Mobile specific events, in this case you're probably looking for `pageload`/`pagecreate`/`pageinit`, see documentation about them here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Here is a quick example of how this could work (this code would be located centrally and included in each document):

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#occasions", loaded);
```

Note that `#occasions` would be the `data-role="page"` element in the occasions page.

Comment: $(document).bind("pagechange", function (event, data) {
            var toPage = data.toPage[0].id;
            if (toPage == "page2")
                alert("hello");
        });

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT

Actually, since you use jquery mobile, probably you are looking the problem in a different place.

So, going to [jquery mobile api](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) we see that we kinda need `pagechange` or `pageload` event.

Comment: @crush, user1853803 also stated within his OP, _"**If i remove the jquery** files, then it works as expected"_, so my comment above is a _reminder_ that this answer works but it _requires_ jQuery.

Comment: @Sparky The `document.ready` suggestion will not work with pages jQuery Mobile grabs via AJAX, which is the default method. By removing jQuery, you're not using jQuery Mobile and just opening the link normally, rather than using AJAX when jQuery/jQM is loaded.

Comment: @Jasper, yes thanks... I already understand that.  I made my initial comments because the OP never mentions jQuery **Mobile**.  Yes, I know, I missed it buried in his code.  I've now edited his title to make this more clear.