# Why my jquery code does not work on mobile?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on a project on WordPress, and have code, that works on desktop, but not on mobile.

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.tm-range-picker').each(function(){
        if ( ! noUiSlider ) {
        } else {
            var $this = jQuery(this);
            $this.get( 0 ).noUiSlider.on( 'update', function (values, handle){
                var value = values[handle];
                value = value.replace(/,/g, '');
                $this.parents('.tc-quantity-top').find('.tm-qty').val( value );
                $this.parents('.tc-quantity-top').find('.tm-qty').change();
            } );
        }
    });
    jQuery( ".tm-qty" ).change(function(event) {
        var max = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('max'));
        var min = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('min'));
        if (jQuery(this).val() > max)
        {
            jQuery(this).val(max);
        }
        else if (jQuery(this).val() < min)
        {
            jQuery(this).val(min);
        }
        if(typeof( event.isTrigger ) != "undefined" && event.isTrigger !== null) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parents('.tc-quantity-top').find('.tm-range-picker').get( 0 ).noUiSlider.set( jQuery(this).val() );
        }
    });
});
```

It can render the file, but the code doesn't work.

Comment: What's the error ? If no error have tried logging anything to console.

Comment: check this I think this is help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734675/using-jquery-mobile-onload-function-not-firing-in-html